# Is the an R function to "multiply" individual characters in a string?

Tags: r, permutation

```
string1 <- c("AB", "CD", "EF")
string2 <- c("E", "GH)

string1 string2 output

AB      E       AE, BE
CD      GH      CG, CH, DG, DH
EF              E, F
```

For row 1, it could be either A and B, but never A and B with E.

This is what I have so far:

unique(strsplit(x, ""))

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "E"
```

I also know I have to use the combn() function, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After splitting the two strings with `""`, use `Map` to loop over the corersponding elements, create a `matrix` of combinations with `outer`, while specifying the `FUN` as `paste` to concat the individual elements, `unlist` the `list` output after `paste`ing the vector of strings to a single string (`toString`) and create a data.frame with the strings and the output as columns

```
output <- unlist(Map(function(x, y) toString(sort(c(outer(x, 
    if(length(y) == 0) "" else y, FUN = paste0)))), 
        strsplit(string1, ""), strsplit(string2, "")))

data.frame(string1, string2, output)
#  string1 string2         output
#1      AB       E         AE, BE
#2      CD      GH CG, CH, DG, DH
#3      EF                   E, F
```

NOTE: The `if` make sure that if there is string with only blank (`""`) element, it won't return `character(0)`

---

If there are more than 2 strings, use `expand.grid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
output <-  mget(ls(pattern = "^string\\d+$")) %>% 
    transpose %>% 
    map_chr(~ {
       x1 <- strsplit(unlist(.), "")
       x1[lengths(x1) == 0] <- ''
       expand.grid(x1) %>% 
           invoke(paste0, .) %>%
           toString
     } ) 

mget(ls(pattern = "^string\\d+$")) %>%
    as_tibble %>%
    mutate(output = output)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#  string1 string2 string3 output                                
#  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                                 
#1 AB      "E"     FH      AEF, BEF, AEH, BEH                    
#2 CD      "GH"    NG      CGN, DGN, CHN, DHN, CGG, DGG, CHG, DHG
#3 EF      ""      C       EC, FC
```

#### data

```
string1 <- c("AB", "CD", "EF")
string2 <- c("E", "GH", "")
string3 <- c("FH", "NG", "C")
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! How would this work if there was one more (string3) column? :o

Comment: @TheresaUyenLe if there are more than 2 strings, perhaps `expand.grid` would be an option

Comment: @TheresaUyenLe i updated with a more general case